# SegFault when passing functions in C

Tags: c, function, struct, function-pointers

I'm getting a SegFault when passing a function pointer through a couple of structs and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's the code:

```
typedef int (*CompareFuncT)( void *, void * );
typedef void (*DestructFuncT)( void * );

struct AVL
{
    void * obj;

    struct AVL * parent;
    struct AVL * leftChild;
    struct AVL * rightChild;
};
typedef struct AVL * AVLPtr;

struct SortedList
{
    AVLPtr root;
    CompareFuncT comp;
    DestructFuncT dest;
};
typedef struct SortedList * SortedListPtr;

SortedListPtr SLCreate(CompareFuncT cf, DestructFuncT df){
    SortedListPtr slp = malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));
    if(slp == NULL){
        printf("Not enough space for list\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    slp->root = NULL;
    slp->comp = cf;
    slp->dest = df;

    return slp;
}

AVLPtr avl_insert(AVLPtr root, AVLPtr parent, void * obj, int (*compare)(     void *, void * )){

    int s = 5;
    int k = 6;
    compare(&s, &k);
    if(root == NULL){
        root = malloc(sizeof(struct AVL));
        if(root == NULL){
            printf ("Out of memory - creating AVL node\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        root->obj = obj;
        root->parent = parent;
        root->leftChild = NULL;
        root->rightChild = NULL;
        return root;
    }

    else if (compare(obj, root->obj) < 0){

        root->leftChild = avl_insert(root->leftChild, root, obj, compare);
        root = balance(root);
    }

    else if (compare(obj, root->obj) >= 0){
        root->rightChild = avl_insert(root->rightChild, root, obj, compare);
        root = balance(root);
    }

    return root;
}

int SLInsert(SortedListPtr list, void * newObj){
    list->root = avl_insert(list->root, newObj, list->comp);
    if(list->root == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}


int compareInts(void *p1, void *p2)
{
    int i1 = *(int*)p1;
    int i2 = *(int*)p2;

    return i1 - i2;
}

void destroyBasicTypeNoAlloc(void *p) {
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int s = 9;

    SortedListPtr list = SLCreate(compareInts, destroyBasicTypeNoAlloc);

    SLInsert(list, &s);


    return 0;

}
```

There's obviously more parameters going through the function, but this is the propagation of my compare function. I'm getting a SegFault on the compare in avl_insert. I have a feeling I'm just not passing a pointer where I should be, but I just can't find it.

Comment: What's all this `list->root` stuff? The `struct` you posted doesn't have `root` as a member.

Comment: `SLInsert()` doesn't call `afl_insert()` with the correct number of parameters. When fixing that so it compiles everything seems to work without segfaults.

Comment: Yeah my header file didn't have my updated version so it wasn't throwing me an error. Once I posted the full code I noticed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is your call of `malloc`:

```
 SortedListPtr slp = malloc(sizeof(SortedListPtr));
```

You are allocating the number of bytes that a pointer takes up, which is incorrect.  It should be:

```
 SortedListPtr slp = malloc(sizeof(struct SortedList));
```

Comment: I'm still getting a segfault at the same line. I don't need to malloc the CompareFuncT, do I (since its a pointer)?

Comment: Cannot duplicate: http://ideone.com/BtZ1vh  Also, there is no need to malloc the function pointer.  You're assigning the address of an existing function, so there is no problem.

Comment: How should I debug if you cannot duplicate? Any tips?

Comment: @JeremyRosenberg: Posting your real code would be a helpful place to start. Posting fake code wastes everyone's time.

Comment: Will do, but abstracting to the issue saves everyone time. Unless of course I've misinterpreted the issue haha

Comment: Wow, I think I figured it out. Header file wasnt updated for a newer version of avl_insert, will update in a moment.

Comment: And that's exactly why posting fake code wastes everyone's time.